# mysql LOAD DATA INFILE EXCLUDE UNWANTED ROWS

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to import the all the product rows and exclude the unnecessary rows. My code below is working but it is importing the rows i want to exclude. I'm now trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE to select the rows I want to import. Any help?

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$file_mimes)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
            $csv_file = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");
                fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",");


                while(($emp_record = fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
                    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM ppmp_supply_order WHERE order_stock_no = '".$emp_record[1]."'";
                    $resultset = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultset)) {
                        $sql_update = "UPDATE ppmp_supply_order set 
                                            prefix = '".$emp_record[0]."',
                                            order_stock_no='".$emp_record[1]."', 
                                            order_unit='".$emp_record[2]."' , 
                                            order_name='".$emp_record[3]."' , 
                                            order_current_price='".$emp_record[5]."' , 
                                            order_unit_price='".$emp_record[6]."' ,
                                            order_qty='".$emp_record[7]."',
                                                WHERE order_stock_no = '".$emp_record[1]."'";
                        mysqli_query($con, $sql_update) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
                    } else{
                        $mysql_insert = "INSERT INTO ppmp_supply_order (prefix, order_stock_no, order_unit, order_name, order_current_price, order_unit_price, order_qty )
                                            VALUES('".$emp_record[0]."','".$emp_record[1]."', '".$emp_record[2]."', '".$emp_record[3]."', '".$emp_record[5]."', '".$emp_record[6]."', '".$emp_record[7]."')";
                        mysqli_query($con, $mysql_insert) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
                    }

                }
                fclose($csv_file);
```

[This is what i want as an output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkRhN.png)

[This is my result so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mNXC.png)

[This is the csv file im trying to import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mNXC.png)

Comment: The PHP code you pasted above seems to have little to do with `LOAD DATA`, though I will tell you `LOAD DATA` is a fairly inflexible data loading tool.  It is possible to skip some initial lines/headers, but not to skip random lines throughout the file.

Comment: How about skip headers and footers?

Comment: Not sure about footers, but skipping headers is possible.  You can skip footers by specifying how many lines you want to read I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to ignore random lines. It can be told to skip a certain number of header rows but that's all.

If you need to ignore some rows you can import the data into a temporary table then use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) to copy the desired rows into the final table.

Comment: Oh never thought of that one. Thanks! You solved my problem.